# Remove array elements based on value supplied

Tags: php

If I had an array like this...

`array('1','2','3','4','10')`

... how could I remove elements before the element whose value I supply.

For example:

If I supplied `1` then `array = (1,2,3,4,10)`

If it were `2` then `array = (2,3,4,10) //Remove the numbers before 2`

If it were `3` then `array = (3,4,10) //Remove the numbers before 3`

If it were `4` then `array = (4,10) //Remove the numbers before 4`

If it were `10` then `array = (10) //Remove all before the 10`

I'm currently thinking of doing with using `if else`. But is there a way to do this using some kind of php array function itself.

Comment: If an enumerative array, use [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the element key, and then use [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker My array is just like the one in my question. $array = array("1","2","3","4","10")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
<?php
$arr=array_slice($arr, array_search('4',array('1','2','3','4','10')));
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 10
)
```

[<kbd>`Demo`</kbd>](https://eval.in/94593)

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array('1','2','3','4','10');
$value = 3;

$key = array_search($value, $myArray);
$myNewArray = array_splice($myArray, 0, $key);
```

Comment: You've got several things mixed up in your answer. Eg: $myArray and $value in the 3rd line and the offset in the fourth line.

Comment: And your final output are the number before the supplied number, while it should have been the ones after it.

Comment: Hmmmm, I execute it with $value=3 and I get a `$myArray` value of `[3,4,10]` and `$myNewArray` value of `[1,2]` which I thought was your expectation... you can discard $myNewArray if you want and simply use `array_splice($myArray, 0, $key);` to update `$myArray`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help:

```
 $myArray = array('1','2','3','4','10');
 $x=3;
 $myArray = array_splice($myArray, array_search($x, $myArray), count($myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($filterItem) {
    return $item !== $filterItem;
});
```

Will filter out every item equal to `$filterItem`. [array_filter on php.net](http://php.net/array_filter)